# This was not my original idea

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is old advice
>
> My infix will guide you away
>
> My suffix is my own
>
> My whole was not right the first time

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word is

> **REDETERMINE**

---

My prefix is old advice

> [**REDE**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rede) - An archaic word for advice

My infix will guide you away

> **DETER**

My suffix is my own

> **MINE**

My whole was not right the first time

> **REDETERMINE** means to re-evaluate something